# More examples of non-split algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, local-field, reductive-groups

I'm reading *Reductive Groups over Local Fields* by Tits (from the Corvallis proceedings), and I'm having trouble making sense of several of the definitions, especially when it comes to the local Dynkin diagram. For example, I don't know any examples of groups with non-reduced root systems or with any affine roots $\alpha$ such that $d(\alpha) > 1$ (Here this means that the subgroup $U_\alpha$ corresponding to $\alpha$ has $\dim{(U_\alpha / U_{\alpha + \varepsilon})} > 1$). I think it may be helpful to familiarize myself with a more diverse set of examples of non-split groups to apply these definitions to.

I know Tits has a complete classification of groups by local Dynkin diagrams in section 4, but they are given only by "name" (e.g. $^4D_4$), "affine root system" (e.g. $C\text-BC^{I\!I\!I}_1$), and "index" (e.g. $^2D^{(2)}_{4,1}$), whereas I would hope to find some constructive information about the groups themselves—for instance, involving restriction of scalars or units groups of algebras.

My previous main examples of non-split groups, $SU_n$ and restriction of scalars of a split group over a quadratic extension, do not seem powerful enough to make sense of these definitions. In particular, anisotropic groups have no roots and are trivial as a source of examples. Does anyone know a good source for constructive examples of a diverse range of non-split algebraic groups?

Comment: Just a quick comment: googling "classical groups" brings up lots of freely available things. For an old reference, A. Weil's "Algebras with involutions and classical groups" (maybe in French?) proves that the algebra-with-involution approach does yield all the A,B,C,D-type groups, over various fields.

Comment: Are you familiar with non-split groups over $\mathbb R$, first and foremost, the orthogonal groups $SO(p,q)$coming from bilinear forms with non-trivial signature? Then, things coming from quaternions? In any case, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3132957/96384. More generally, Tits' article in the Boulder proceedings, refernced e.g. in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930354/96384, is a great source.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I'm not as familiar as I should be—is $SO(p, q)$ not always anisotropic over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: No it's not. For $SO(p,q)$ with even $p+q$, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3738143/96384. For some possible confusion regarding terminology, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3188931/96384.